# Python Pandas Market Calendars day count (Trading day vs Calendar Days)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I am conducting some market research and one of the variables I am investigating is the distribution of time for an event to occur as a log distribution and create a cumulative probability density function as a function of time.  ( I simply convert my dates as so:

```
A=datetime.strptime(UDate1[0],date_format) 
B=datetime.strptime(UDate2[0],date_format)
```

and I can subtract  like so:

```
C=(A-B).days
```

and I am returned an integer of the number of days.. 5, 6, 10, 11..  whatever it may be).

My data should fit a log distribution,however, because I am currently using calendar days and my events only occur on market days ... it is an unacceptable source of error, and it creates empty histograms within my distribution (days 6 and 7 are always zero (weekends), and holiday effects).

I cannot calculate an accurate cumulative distribution function in this way so I recently downloaded the Pandas Market Calendar. Does anyone have experience figuring out how to calculate trading days vs market days.  For example if I was looking at the time from July 19, 2020 to July 13, 2020. It would be 12 Calendar days, but only 8 trading days.

Answer (score 3):

Info on the Pandas Market Calendars is here:
https://pypi.org/project/pandas-market-calendars/

First, create a market data object as described in the link:

```
import pandas_market_calendars as mcal

# Create a calendar
nyse = mcal.get_calendar('NYSE')

early = nyse.schedule(start_date='2012-07-01', end_date='2012-07-10')

print(mcal.date_range(early, frequency='1D'))

DatetimeIndex(['2012-07-02 20:00:00+00:00', '2012-07-03 17:00:00+00:00',
               '2012-07-05 20:00:00+00:00', '2012-07-06 20:00:00+00:00',
               '2012-07-09 20:00:00+00:00', '2012-07-10 20:00:00+00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', freq=None)
```

Now, create a series with value of ones, and indexed by *market* days.  Then re-index on *calendar* days, and fill missing values with zeros.  Compute cumulative sum, and number of trading days between two dates is difference between cumulative sums at different dates:

```
import pandas as pd

bus_day_index = pd.DatetimeIndex(
    ['2012-07-02 20:00:00+00:00', '2012-07-03 17:00:00+00:00',
     '2012-07-05 20:00:00+00:00', '2012-07-06 20:00:00+00:00',
     '2012-07-09 20:00:00+00:00', '2012-07-10 20:00:00+00:00'],
    dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', freq=None)

bus_day_index = bus_day_index.normalize()

s = pd.Series(data=1, index=bus_day_index)

cal_day_index = pd.date_range(start=bus_day_index.min(), end=bus_day_index.max())

s = s.reindex(index=cal_day_index).fillna(0).astype(int)

s = s.cumsum()

s['2012-07-09'] - s['2012-07-03']
```

Advantage:  This (inelegant) method incorporates non-trading days that fall on weekdays (Memorial Day, Labor Day, etc. in the U.S.).

Comment: What does the s.reindex do near the bottom?

Comment: s.reindex() changes from indexing by trading date to indexing by calendar date.  All the new dates (i.e., elements in the index) will be populated with NaN values.  Then the fillna() will change them to zeros.

Comment: This method works well. You are right it is not the most elegant but it does the job. It seems if I choose a starting date that falls on a weekend, or ends on a weekend it ends up with an error in this line of code  s['2012-07-09'] - s['2012-07-03']  ; however, because all my dad is picked on actual market days.. that shouldn't occur

Comment: You could make `cal_day_index` start earlier and end later; that may eliminate the error you mentioned.  For example: `date_range.min() - pd.DateOffset(days=10)` (note the DateOffset).  And add N days to the end of the range.  I don't know of any library that performs date adjustments (modified-following convention, Act/365 day count convention, etc.)

Comment: Its okay brother because up until this part of the code ive already scanned through a 20 years loock back period of market data and  so all dates I have in my database are based on market open dates. I am currently adjusted your suggested code into an iteration into the my program and its working. Big thank you!

Answer (score -1):

From your question it sounds like you want to count the number of trading days. If so please try the following out:

```
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta

start_date = A
end_date = B
delta = timedelta(days=1)
count = 0
while start_date <= end_date:
    print (start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    if start_date.weekday() <=5:
       count +=1
    start_date += delta
print(count)
```

Comment: This code counts the number of Monday to Friday days included in the period - this is NOT the same as the number of trading days! There are holidays and other closures that have to be taken into account.

Comment: I'm pondering a similar problem.  Wondering if any of  the typical languages: C,  C++ ,  Perl, Ruby, Swift, Python, etc. provide  a US Market  Calendar in the language?

I really hate having to validate that  my one-off idea  of time... might work.